# Scipy.optimize - minimize does not give same results as Excel

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I need to implement similiar functionality like in Excel solver with GRG alghorithm with some constraints.
I have the following table:

**| Profit|Utility|**

| 10 |0,25|

| 20 |0,5|

And I have three variables: x1, x2, x3

Because there is no library which would support GRG (at least not for free) I tried to use SLSQP alghorithm.
So I am trying to minimaze the following function (for this table):

```
(x1*math.exp(-10/x2) + x3) - 0.25)**2 + (x1*math.exp(-20/x2) + x3) - 0.5)**2
```

And **x1** must be positive, **x2** must be negative, so I used bounds instead of constraints (which I dont know if it is ok).

So I have the following script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math

def objective_fcn(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]

    return ((x1*math.exp(-10/x2) + x3) - 0.25)**2 + ((x1*math.exp(-20/x2) + x3) - 0.5)**2

bounds_x1 = [None, 0]
bounds_x2 = [0, None]
bounds_x3 = [None, None]

bounds = [bounds_x1, bounds_x2, bounds_x3]

x0 = [-1, 1, 1]

result = minimize(objective_fcn, x0, method="SLSQP", bounds=bounds)

print(result)
```

Problem is that Excel with GRG returns totally different values of x1,x2,x3 and even function. And in Excel I am setting up inital values as (1, -1, 1) as well. So I might have chosen wrong alghorithm in Scipy or my code must be wrong.
In case this alghoritm is not suitable for this task, would you recommend different one?

**Python script results**

x: array([**x1**=-1.00001703,**x2**=1.00017025,**x3**=0.37502273])

**fun**: 0.031238632038406017

**Excel results**

**x1**=-2,37644086849453;**x2**=4,7066297954663;**x3**=0,533921109144656

**fun**: 1,86E-14

[image: Excel]

Excel function in utility f: `=$O$6*EXP(-E6/$P$6)+$Q$6`
SSE function: `=SUMSQ(H6:H7)`

**Also Excel solver:**
[image: Solver]

Thank you

Comment: What does your Excel function look like?  If you pass your Excel numbers into `objective_fcn`, the result is 0.062477, not 4.65E-10, so the math is not the same.

Comment: @TimRoberts I added more Excel information

Comment: Why do you have -0.25 in the first half of the equation but -0.5 in the second half?  If I change the first to -0.5, I get results much closer to Excel's results.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, sorry, I was also testing it with -0,5 on both sides and the results are very close then... but when I put different values for both sides, the result are not close at all for whatever reason... (And I changed excel picture so It correspons to script). And script should hande much morer data (multiple rows in excel) so there will be a lot of different values in column "utility"... so it is quite a problem that python script gives me then different values then

Comment: It's quite clear that SLSQP is the wrong choice.  Add code in `objective_fcn` to print out the inputs and the result, and you'll see it only tries about 10 points.  You should try the "TNC" method; it matches Excel to 2 decimal places.  I suspect your function has many local minima.

Comment: Ok thank you. It did really help for my the function above. Almost same value for function, x1, x2 and x3. But I also tried to make the function bigger because that will definitely happen so the function was: (x1*math.exp(-10/x2) + x3) - 0.25)**2 + (x1*math.exp(-20/x2) + x3) - 0.5)**2 + ((x1*math.exp(-10/x2) + x3) - 0.25)**2; In this case the values for x1, x2, x3 were different but value of function was almost identical as SSE in excel (excel function). Does it still work good? Is it possible that my python script still finds a good minima with different x1, x2, x3 and similiar value of func?

Comment: I also tried to play a little with xtol ftol and I was even able to get better values than excel (as far as function value is concerned) but not the same.